# Break apart a dataframe into individual named vectors

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there an easy function, outside of attach/detach, that will break apart a dataframe or data table into its individual vectors with the names of the vectors as the names of the columns in the dataframe.

For example,  suppose I have a data frame
`x <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6), d=c(7,8,9))`

Then using the function it would return 3 vectors: `a`, `b`, and `d`.  Seems like there should be function to do this but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be  `list2env`

```
list2env(x,.GlobalEnv)

a
#[1] 1 2 3
b
#[1] 4 5 6
d
#[1] 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a (very old, very standard) function called `attach()` that does that:

```
> x <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6), d=c(7,8,9))
> attach(x)
> a
[1] 1 2 3
> b
[1] 4 5 6
> d
[1] 7 8 9
>
```

*However*, the general consensus is to *Don't Do That (TM)* as it can a) clutter the environment into which you `attach()` (usually the global one) and can b) silently overwrite an existing variable (though it warns by default unless you override a switch, see `?attach`).  There is a counterpart `detach()` to remove them too.  The (aptly named) Section "Good Practice" in the help page for `attach` has more on all this, including a hint to use `on.exit()` with `detach()` where you use `attach()`.

But if you need it, you can use it.  Just be aware of Them Dragons.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. Many introductory books on R use attach and detach willy-nilly in my opinion to make things easy to read and I used it for a long time when I was first starting. It’s only when you start putting it in functions and such that you start to  realize it’s pernicious side effects. My klewgie work around to this problem was to loop over the columns, create a string of name = as.vector and then parse/eval.  It works but it is not pretty and far from elegant.

Comment: It however _exactly_ answers _your question_.  <Shrug_and_grin_emoji_here>.  And both `list2env` and `attach` allow you to place the components into a _different environment_ if you so choose.  (Also, you and I show our age here. _Old_ books did in the day. Current books mostly don't mention it.)

Answer (score 0):

While two answers have already been posted, I would like to suggest a solution that does not write to the global environment, which is generally considered to be a bad thing (see Dirk´s comments on `attach`).

First of all, R can only return single objects. It is not possible to return three, separate vectors. However, we can easily return *a list* of vectors.

```r
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6), d=c(7,8,9))

# Returns a named list
as.list(df)
#> $a
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> $d
#> [1] 7 8 9
```